# Azure WebJob Triggered by WebPost Request

Tags: azure, http-post, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

Is it possible to trigger the execution of the web job from post request? My scenario is that the job is waiting for data provider to post data over https and this should trigger the data processing- parsing of the data then applying some business actions.
I can see a lot of examples with queues and it is easy to test and make your own but not sure how to fill the queue except manually to enter some data. Is it possible to fill a queue with http post data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [Azure ServiceBus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus/) Queue.

  Azure Webjobs have a [ServicebusTrigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#trigger) that you can use in your
  scenario.

  If you can't use the client library you can send messages to a queue over http :

  [Service Bus brokered messaging REST tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/)
- Otherwise if your message is too large, you can store your message into an Azure Storage Blob. Azure Webjobs have a [BlobTrigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/). But there is some restrictions :

  > The WebJobs SDK scans log files to watch for new or changed blobs. This process is not real-time; a function might not get triggered until several minutes or longer after the blob is created. In addition, [storage logs are created on a "best efforts"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-service-bus/#trigger) basis; there is no guarantee that all events will be captured. Under some conditions, logs might be missed. If the speed and reliability limitations of blob triggers are not acceptable for your application, the recommended method is to create a queue message when you create the blob, and use the [QueueTrigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/) attribute instead of the `BlobTrigger` attribute on the function that processes the blob.

Comment: I can see how your idea might work. My concern now is that the messages that are been send from the service bus will be too large - maybe about 2-3 MB xml data. In my case probably is better to setup a simple web app that will catch all the post requests and will save them somewhere in DB. Then that will create a message in message queue that will be processed by webjob listening for change. I even think why not do the process in the web app itself as the queue can be process with some dely. I need a message to be processed immediately as it arrives and the solution to be scalable.

Comment: The message that the webjob will receive will be just that there is new item received and then will read the xml data from DB. Isn't that too complicated thinking? It will be easy to scale I can increase the number of jobs, not sure about the web app that is actually receiving the data - I guess can be done using load balancer. What I will probably do is initially is the simplest solution.

Comment: so you can use a blob storage. there is a blobtrigger for webjob. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/. I ll edit my post tomorrow.

Comment: yes that is an option. looks ok, I will need to research more about service buss and see if I can use that, but in the example I described queue or blob storage trigger will be fine